# Replacing/Removing forward slashes from files and folder

Tags: shell-script, backup, lubuntu

I'm running Linux Lubuntu.

I've been looking for a way to replace/remove forward slashes `/` from filenames and foldernames (created with MAC computers) with a shell script **only for my backup files**.

I've searched and apparently, neither did **Areca Backup** neither anyone else tried to remove these slashes while doing a backup before. Couldn't find any piece of info of to how to check filenames and foldernames and rename those with slashes but I do have a feeling after what I read that it is probably with `sed`.

Maybe anyone has at least a little piece of info of how this "Preprocessing scripts" from Areca Backup works, would be really great.

**Examples** (as I mentioned, I wouldlike this to be effective in the backup only if possible)

*Filename Before:* `foo/bar.jpg`

*Filename After:* `foobar.jpg`

Comment: A filename can't contain `/`?  Are you talking about a path to a filename?  Please edit the question and give us an example of what you have before hand and what you'd like to see afterwards.

Comment: Added an example. Hope it's more clear to you now.

Comment: How are you viewing the file names? With what command? Are they embedded in some backup file or as individual files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo 'foo/bar.jpg' | sed 's|/||g'
```

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for. The file itself is named with a forward slash as I showed in the example above. The file is stored on an afp network share so I guess it was accepted the way it was named.

Comment: echo 'foo/bar.jpg' | sed 's|/||g'

Comment: Please check my updated answer as per your modified question

Comment: Now this is what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` to eliminate `/` from paths:

```
someFile="/path/to/some/file"
sed -e 's./..g' <<< "${someFile}
pathtosomefile
```

Comment: As mentioned in the example above, the file name itself contains a forward slashes, no the path.

Comment: @HanselF. As mentioned in a comment above, a file name cannot contain forward slashes.  Also note that the answer you accepted is the same as the answer that I provided here.